# Hmc visibility issue: Attribute not readable to others except admin

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am not able to see the members list of a user group when I log in hmc by other user (not admin). I have given user rights to this user on this attribute and it's strange because I am able to see the attribute when I double click. I can add new attribute but not see those attributes in list. Please see the screen shot.

How to resolve this issue? I tried in Experts forum also but couldn't find any solution. Could anyone suggest me how to approach the issue? Any ideas, links are gladly welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has to do something with the access rights of the login user. Have a look at the "Access Restriction" Tab on  the customer type. I thin there you shoul configure it, that is readable by everyone.

Comment: yeah i did, i have given public access to everyone